# ASP.NET Core Microsoft authentication callbackpage page not found

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, windows-authentication

I have implemented Microsoft authentication using IIS Express and everything worked as expected (like the one from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

However after I publish it to IIS, when a user tries to access the application, instead of the Microsoft login page, I get a page with the message

> No webpage was found for the web address: <redirecturl>?code=...

I should mention that there is no other way to login. Only the Microsoft one has to be supported.

Comment: Have you set up a callback/redirect URL in Microsoft auth dashboard? (I haven't used MS auth, but it (or any other OIDC provider) should ask you for a URL)

Comment: Yes i have. That was the page that he can not found.

Comment: Have you enabled the middleware for forwarding headers (from proxies)? I mean `app.UseForwardedHeaders()`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: No I did not. Could it be because of this? But why doesn't the IIS Express need it?

Comment: Which version of Asp.net core version you are using? When using IIS Express to check your application, try to use F12 developer tool check the redirect URL, whether it use the same URL (the redirect URL in IIS)? Besides, can you create a sample to reproduce the problem and share it to use via Github or OneDrive, so, we can work together to figure it out.

Comment: @abdusco I tried to use the UseForwardHeaders and it did not help.

Comment: @Zhi Lv version 3.1. It is not the same url cause on the IIS Express I use the localhost while the IIS uses the site name. (The microsoft login was configured to return the correct address for both of the sites). However the redirect is the same as the one configured in both cases. Unfortunately my company does not allow me to have the IIS on my machine so only after publishing on server I have discovered this issue.

Comment: Do you have access to application logs? Crank up the log levels to `Debug` and try to log in to see how the app behaves.

Comment: @abdusco The logging on this application is configured to log only very little thing, but its a good idea to log more. I will do this and see if I can get to a cz

Comment: @abdusco It seems indeed there is an error in the logging, but its stored as Info: ||INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountHandler|Error from RemoteAuthentication: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..|

Comment: You probably have a typo in the URL. Or DNS can't resolve the hostname. Or just a transient error.

Comment: There is no typo in the URL. After further investigation because the IIS is behind a proxy I had to configure that too. But I have discovered something puzzling. If I try to get the token using the Postman it gives me the correct response while in the application I still get connection refused. I was getting the same error on Postman before configuring the proxy. So it seems that from the IIS does not recognize the proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I found out from where the problem was.

The server was protected and the IIS did not have access to the internet and a proxy was required. Hence the reason on IIS Express was working on the development machine but on the server IIS did not.